FailOverManager - Error - The computer is joined to a cluster
I try connect a new server in FileOverManager and I get error "The computer is joined to a cluster".
But this server is not connect to the cluster. First attempt crashed to timeout.
Do I understand correctly that I must run this command in Powershell?
Clear-ClusterNode -Name ServerName -Force
Or I have to run another command?

It is correct command. After run I can re-add the same server to cluster.
